# Adding Signal on Stochastic Oscillator

Tags: pine-script

I need to add signals in the shape of circles on stochastic oscillator in tradingview. When the signal line crosses under 80 there I need a red circle. When the signal crosses over the 20 line there I need a green signal. How can I do that? Please help. Below is the pine script of Stochastic Oscillator from TradingView -

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Stochastic", shorttitle="Stoch", format=format.price, precision=2, timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)
periodK = input.int(14, title="%K Length", minval=1)
smoothK = input.int(1, title="%K Smoothing", minval=1)
periodD = input.int(3, title="%D Smoothing", minval=1)
k = ta.sma(ta.stoch(close, high, low, periodK), smoothK)
d = ta.sma(k, periodD)
plot(k, title="%K", color=#2962FF)
plot(d, title="%D", color=#FF6D00)
h0 = hline(80, "Upper Band", color=#787B86)
hline(50, "Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
h1 = hline(20, "Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(h0, h1, color=color.rgb(33, 150, 243, 90), title="Background")
```

Thanks for your time. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ta.crossover()` and `ta.crossunder()` functions for this. In order to plot the circles on the signal line, you are going to need `location=location.absolute`.

```
k_co = ta.crossover(k, 20)
k_cu = ta.crossunder(k, 80)

plotshape(k_co ? k : na, "Crossover", shape.circle, location.absolute, color.green)
plotshape(k_cu ? k : na, "Crossunder", shape.circle, location.absolute, color.red)
```